# Is there a standard resource that lists all understood particle-particle relationships?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model

I am just starting to dig a little deeper into particle interactions, and just have an introductory college physics background (no quantum mechanics). But I am interested in the conditions of the early universe and am looking for a list of all the particles in the standard model, and the relationships between the particles, so you can see which particles turn into other particles under which conditions, and stuff like that.

Is there any such a thing? Or if not, it would be really cool to see a list of all the particles in the early universe and the different types of interactions they had with each other. Such as:

- What happens when a quark + antiquark come close together? What if they collide?
- What happens when 2 gluons collide? Come close together?
- What happens when 1 quark and 1 gluon come together?
- What happens when 2 photons collide (can they collide?)?
- What particles radiate photons? Under what conditions?
- ...

Does such a resource exist? Or if not, where would you go about finding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Particle Data Book, published by the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) is probably the nearest to what you're asking for. The actual book is a massive tome costing a fortune. I'm not sure how much of and in what form it's online, but some intrepid Googling should find you most of what you want.

As fqq points out the book is available from [Phys. Rev. D vol. 86 Issue 1](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.86.010001)

Comment: The last (2012) version of both the full Review of Particle Physics and the pocket-size Particle Physics Booklet are available for free on the PDG website. The former is PhysRevD 86 010001.

Comment: Is that the best place to get the raw particle physics data from things like the LHC too? Or where would that be found? I can ask another question if that's best.